# A friend shared interview questions with me

Tags: interviewing, ethics, employment

A friend who works for the company I applied, gave me the technical interview questions without me asking. I knew answers to most part of the questions but I got tempted to read through the questions and answers.
The day after the interview, I go t the job offer. I felt bad about it so I called the person who did the technical interview and told him I knew the questions (without mentioning how) and if he thinks it is cheating, he can tell me so I just reject the job offer so they could get one of the other candidates. He said it is not a big deal and the interview process is not that technical anyway.  He said they wanted just to know my personality and if I fit in their team. He also said if I have worked in the field for so many years, I would be able to do the job. He told me I am over reacting and I should not be worried.
I still feel bad because of other candidates and do not know if I should reject the job offer. They have put time and resource on interviewing me and I do not want it to go to waste. I also do the job for many years and I think I could have answered the questions without having them before the interview.

Comment: ..and what exactly is your question? Do you need some confirmation that it was the right choice to tell the interviewer that you knew the answers?

Comment: @iLuvLogix My question is whether I should reject the job offer because the process was not 100% fair.

Comment: _"He told me I am over reacting and I should not be worried. [...]  I also do the job for many years and I think I could have answered the questions without having them before the interview."_ - There is your answer..

Comment: If the interview process relies on the questions being secret, it's a terrible process.

Comment: As long as you feel qualified for the job, take it. As far as it being unfair, businesses can have an impressively narrow conception of fairness. You will certainly see much worse than this in your career.

Comment: Friend of mine did this unintentionally. Applied at some big company. Everyone was given an IQ test. Two days later he interviewed at a different company. He was given the exact same IQ test. Got one of the highest results they had ever seen.

Answer (score 18):

> I still feel bad because of other candidates and do not know if I should reject the job offer.

Don't reject the offer. The company already said they don't care, so there's no reason to reject it because of this. If anything, if you reject now, you're just going to cost the company more money (since they have to possibly do another round of interviews if they have nobody else lined up).

I think you did the right thing in telling them about it, but they've said it's fine, so no reason to worry about it anymore.

> I also do the job for many years and I think I could have answered the questions without having them before the interview.

Then there's even less reason to worry. You're now just worried because you saw the questions, even though the result would likely have been the same if you hadn't.

Comment: Thanks @Dnomyar96. You gave me peace of mind. I even told him if it is not fair to other candidates, you can get any of them.

Answer (score 12):

If you are wondering what you should do next: take the job. You are overthinking this. You don't pass an interview and get an offer based solely on answering technical questions. They also look at you as a person. You succeeded based on that.

You've been honest, be it after the interview, about having the questions beforehand. This is the best thing you could have done, besides stating before/during the interview you had this. You told them what happened and they do not care, since they believe you have the experience you need for the actual job.

Comment: He sent me the question couple of hours before the interview when I was working. During interview I was stressed. The day after the interview I realised it and got technical interview's phone number from HR and called him.

Comment: Understandable, interviews can be stressful enough without this situation. You did the right thing. They accepted the explanation and now you can be happy that you have a good job offer.